# send images without internet connection objective C

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, attachment, mms

I want to attach images in sms. But without internet connection we can only send sms not mms .Is there any way to send image without internet connection?I have googled it but I couldn't get any solution.Because iPhone does not allow mms without internet.
I m using `MFMessageComposeViewController` but its not working for me.When I am trying to send mms and there is no network connection.then my mms not queuing up for further sending(so that it will send when internet available).I m not getting it in message application of device,Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

You can not send media files through SMS. It supports text and unicode characters only. If you want to send image, audio or video then you need to do it via MMS.So, it is not possible with `MFMessageComposeViewController`.